# Application ELB - sticky sessions based on consistent hashing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I couldn't find anything in the documentation but still writing to make sure I did not miss it. I want all connections from different clients with the same value for a certain request parameter to end up on the same upstream host. With ELB sticky session, you can have the same client connect to the same host but no guarantees across different clients.

This is possible with Envoy proxy, see: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancers#ring-hash

We already use ELB so if the above is possible with ELB then we can avoid introducing another layer in between with envoy.

UPDATE:
Use-case - in a multi-tenant cloud solution, we want all clients from a given customer account to connect to the same upstream host.

Comment: Hi, what’s the usecase?

Comment: @mokugo-devops added the use-case

Comment: Hi, any specific reason why these must be a specific host? Also how do you differentiate this? Different hostname? :)

Comment: application specific reason. We dont need to differentiate upstream host, you can pick any one, just they need to be pinned to the client after initial association.

Comment: @vrtx54234 If you send the "same value for a certain request parameter" in a session-cookie for different clients, then I think you can have "session affinity" as mentioned in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Please let me know your thoughts ?

Comment: @Subbu yes I guess it could work. The next requirement was to couple this with even load across upstream hosts, see hash_balance_factor at https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto.html?highlight=hash_balance_factor#config-cluster-v3-cluster-commonlbconfig-consistenthashinglbconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible to be performed in an ALB.

An application load balancer controls all the logic over which host receives the traffic with features such as ELB sticky sessions and pattern based routing.

If there is no work around then you could look at a [Classic Loadbalancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application) which has support for the application setting the sticky session cookie name and value.

From best practice ideally your application should be stateless, is it possible to look at rearchitecting your app instead of trying work around. Some suggestions I would have are:

- Using [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) to store any session based data, moving from a disk based session (if that's what your application does).
- Any disk based files that need to persist could be shared between all hosts either using [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) for your Linux based hosts, or [FSX](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/) on Windows.
- Medium/Long term persisting files could be migrated to S3, any assets that rarely change could be stored here and then your application could use S3 rather than disk.

It's important to remember that as I stated above, you should keep your application as stateless as you can. Assume that your EC2 instances could fail, by preparing for this it will make it easier to recover.

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you expand a bit on how this would be done using a Classic Load Balancer?

Comment: Regardless of stateless or not, sometimes we need to introduce server side caching for performance.  encouraging requests to go to the same target maximizes the chance of cache hits.
Since writting your comment, Application Load Balancer introduced Application Stickness based on an application cookie, but I feel that won't work for this multi-tenacy case as the value inside the cookie is not considered when assigning stickiness